# How to mutate a data frame to perform a function where the reference group changes?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm still quite new to R but I am trying to add a column into my data frame that performs a function that gives fold change over control. Here is my question applied to this dataset:

```
chemistry    rate Digital biomass[mm^3] greenness average[] Height [mm]
1   Flavone   0.001             135090.45           0.2025817    81.21167
2   Flavone    0.01             144547.00           0.2078100    82.85367
3   Flavone     0.1             145807.70           0.2043300    84.96300
4   Flavone       1             110408.18           0.1949033    81.48700
5   Flavone      10              53585.55           0.1850100    69.78533
6   Flavone Control             138598.08           0.2172325    86.05992
7      SA3F2   0.001              158966.7           0.2051417    85.33000
8      SA3F2    0.01              167762.0           0.2113683    88.58500
9      SA3F2     0.1              159897.5           0.2021017    86.60617
10     SA3F2       1              181713.5           0.1995667    85.57567
11     SA3F2      10              136530.0           0.1964467    81.84200
12     SA3F2 Control              135043.2           0.2179492    86.33429
```

I am trying to have fold change columns for each of the current columns that take the value of each rate of application (grouped by chemistry) and divides it by the control value that corresponds to the chemistry.

For example:

```
Digital biomass fold change 
=134090.45/53585.55
=144547.00/53585.55
```

And so on.

I've grouped the data by chemistry and processed all of the averages. I can't seem to loop this function in a way that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean 134090.45/138598.08 right? That row has a Control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming @StupidWolf's interpretation is correct that you want to divide values from the `"Control"` row in each group for multiple columns using `dplyr`, we can do :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(chemistry) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(`biomass[mm^3]`:`Height[mm]`), ~./.[rateDigital == 'Control'])


#   chemistry rateDigital `biomass[mm^3]` `greenness average[]` `Height[mm]`
#   <fct>     <fct>                 <dbl>                 <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 Flavone   0.001                 0.975                 0.933        0.944
# 2 Flavone   0.01                  1.04                  0.957        0.963
# 3 Flavone   0.1                   1.05                  0.941        0.987
# 4 Flavone   1                     0.797                 0.897        0.947
# 5 Flavone   10                    0.387                 0.852        0.811
# 6 Flavone   Control               1                     1            1    
# 7 SA3F2     0.001                 1.18                  0.941        0.988
# 8 SA3F2     0.01                  1.24                  0.970        1.03 
# 9 SA3F2     0.1                   1.18                  0.927        1.00 
#10 SA3F2     1                     1.35                  0.916        0.991
#11 SA3F2     10                    1.01                  0.901        0.948
#12 SA3F2     Control               1                     1            1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I ask what ~./. means? 
This works perfectly but I am now trying to apply it to adding columns that give me p values for all the results compared to the control value as a reference group.

Comment: @ShailajaChadha `~` is an alternative to writing an anonymous function (Read `?map`) whereas `.` refers to every individual column from `biomass[mm^3]` to `Height[mm]`. So for each column, we are dividing it's value with the corresponding "Control" value of that column.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say this is your data frame:

```
df = structure(list(chemistry = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Flavone", "SA3F2"), class = "factor"), 
    rateDigital = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("0.001", "0.01", "0.1", "1", 
    "10", "Control"), class = "factor"), `biomass[mm^3]` = c(135090.45, 
    144547, 145807.7, 110408.18, 53585.55, 138598.08, 158966.7, 
    167762, 159897.5, 181713.5, 136530, 135043.2), `greenness average[]` = c(0.2025817, 
    0.20781, 0.20433, 0.1949033, 0.18501, 0.2172325, 0.2051417, 
    0.2113683, 0.2021017, 0.1995667, 0.1964467, 0.2179492), `Height[mm]` = c(81.21167, 
    82.85367, 84.963, 81.487, 69.78533, 86.05992, 85.33, 88.585, 
    86.60617, 85.57567, 81.842, 86.33429)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Because of the column names (spaces,special characters etc are a nightmare), i suggest you define the columns to divide over first:

```
CHEMISTRY=1
TYPE = 2
VALUES = 3:5

newvalues = by(df,df[,CHEMISTRY],function(x){
sweep(x[,VALUES],2,as.numeric(x[x[,TYPE]=="Control",3:5]),"/")
})

newvalues = do.call(rbind,newvalues)
newvalues = cbind(df[,1:2],newvalues)
newvalues
          chemistry rateDigital biomass[mm^3] greenness average[] Height[mm]
Flavone.1   Flavone       0.001     0.9746921           0.9325571  0.9436643
Flavone.2   Flavone        0.01     1.0429221           0.9566248  0.9627440
Flavone.3   Flavone         0.1     1.0520182           0.9406051  0.9872540
Flavone.4   Flavone           1     0.7966069           0.8972106  0.9468635
Flavone.5   Flavone          10     0.3866255           0.8516681  0.8108923
Flavone.6   Flavone     Control     1.0000000           1.0000000  1.0000000
SA3F2.7       SA3F2       0.001     1.1771544           0.9412363  0.9883674
SA3F2.8       SA3F2        0.01     1.2422840           0.9698053  1.0260697
SA3F2.9       SA3F2         0.1     1.1840470           0.9272881  1.0031492
SA3F2.10      SA3F2           1     1.3455953           0.9156570  0.9912130
SA3F2.11      SA3F2          10     1.0110098           0.9013417  0.9479663
SA3F2.12      SA3F2     Control     1.0000000           1.0000000  1.0000000
```

You can remove the control using:

```
newvalues[newvalues[,2]!="Control",]
```